# Transforming a path in the shell

Tags: macos, path, zsh

I'm trying to transform a path in the shell in macOS. Does anyone know a quick command for transforming a path as follows?

**Path:**
/Users/nir/MongoDB/GitHub/mms/server/src/unit/com/xgen/svc/nds/aws/model/AWSShardedClusterDescriptionUnitTests.java

**Result:**
//server/src/unit/com/xgen/svc/nds/aws/model:AWSShardedClusterDescriptionUnitTests

The part before /server is replaced with a forward-slash, the last forward-slash is replaced with a colon and the file extension is removed. Thanks in advance!

Comment: If the portion of the path you are replacing is always `/Users/nir/MongoDB/GitHub/mms` then you can just use [substrings](https://stackabuse.com/substrings-in-bash/) and [concatenation](https://linuxize.com/post/bash-concatenate-strings/) to replace the first portion with a slash.

Comment: @NirJacobson : At least show your own attempts in solving the problem, and describe, at which point you got stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to do this.

Setup (with spaces added to the path for testing):

```
input='/Users/user/server/sub/dir s/fil e.java'
expect='//server/sub/dir s:fil e'
p=$input
printf 'before:    "%s"\n' $p
```

Use the `zsh` parameter expansion flag `:r` (root) to remove the extension:

```
p=${p:r}
printf 'root:      "%s"\n' $p
```

Get the dirname and basename with the head and tail parameter expansion
flags, and add a colon:

```
p=${p:h}:${p:t}
printf 'head/tail: "%s"\n' $p
```

Delete the first occurrence of the string `server` and everything before it,
then prepend `//server`:

```
p=//server${p#*server}
printf 'subst:     "%s"\n' $p
[[ $p == $expect ]] && print 'It worked.' || print 'Error.'
```

Combining everything into a single line:

```
p=$input
p=//server${${p:h}#*server}:${p:t:r}
printf 'all:       "%s"\n' $p
[[ $p == $expect ]] && print 'Also worked.' || print 'Error.'
```

Output:

```
before:    "/Users/user/server/sub/dir s/fil e.java"
root:      "/Users/user/server/sub/dir s/fil e"
head/tail: "/Users/user/server/sub/dir s:fil e"
subst:     "//server/sub/dir s:fil e"
It worked.
all:       "//server/sub/dir s:fil e"
Also worked.
```

Most of these operators are documented in the `zshexpn` man page. Somewhat
confusingly, the parameter expansion flags are described in the History
Expansion section.